# Tangent handles in NURBS curves

Tags: bezier-curves

Is it possible to have at the end of a NURBS curve the same kind of handle (**tangent line**) as at the end point of a Bezier curve? Even with a control point set at the end of the curve, the control point lines in a NURBS aren't really tangent lines to the curve.